Manual Lidar Camera calibration using fast-lio pointcloud and odometry
I have a special/strange case, I need to know the extrinsic transform between a Lidar and a  camera or at least camera to IMU. But the problem is that in not all images the checkerboard is visible and the repo's online did not work, and can not easily acces the raw pointcloud frames.
Here is the method I used

Get pointcloud and Odometry from fast-lio (previously made and recorded)
Determine the poses where the images are made.
Get matching 3d points in the pointcloud and 2d points in the image
Transform the 3d points to the frame of the lidar, using the pose (which is taken as IMU as base I assume) and the transform between IMU and Lidar.
Use cv2.solvePnp to get the transform
Do this for multiple image to get an average

but this resulted in big transforms from few meters to decimeters while they are few centimeters apart.
Does anyone have any ideas where the error is, or a way to determine the transform?
